# How to position a table using CSS

Tags: html, css, html-table, position

I have a table with two columns, the right one contains 3 buttons, those buttons change the content in the other column of the table. I want this table to be positioned at the center top of the page but I can't figure out how to do it.

Here is a screenshot of what I want (the image shows a header too, but it's not important for now)

[image: Screenshot]

If it is possible I want the buttons to don't move when the content on the other column changes, but it's not a priority.

I can also change the table with another structure if this will help.

Here is html code:

```
<div class='main'>
<table class="table"> 
    <tr> 
        <td>
            <input type="button" class="button" value="edit_menu"/><br><br>
            <input type="button" class="button" value="edit_desc"/><br><br>
            <input type="button" class="button" value="set_push"/>
        </td>
        <td>
            <div id="content">
                <div id="edit_menu" display="none" class="form">

                            here is a simple form

                </div>

                <div id="edit_desc" display="none" class="form">
                    here is a second form
                </div>

                <div id="set_push" display="none" class="form">
                    here is a third form
                </div>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>   
</table>  
</div>
```

The forms visibility is changed via Javascript when the buttons are pressed.

Comment: well using css `position` you can do this....share your html code so we can help you.

Answer (score 1):

Try using the below code.
css :

```
body {margin:0; padding:0;}
.wrapper {width: 500px /* width of your table*/; margin:0 auto;}
```

html :

```
<div class="wrapper">
 <!-- put your table here -->
</div>
```

Comment: thanks, that worked. but i may want a more generic solution, so i must not change the width value if i change the table

Comment: you can put <table align="center"> property to center the table.

Comment: but this will change the position of the buttons when i click one of them and the content on the left change